# Как учесть в сортировке elasticsearch по полю типа keyword содержащиеся в нем числа

Tags: elasticsearch

Всем, привет!
В результате запроса с multiSearch получаю результаты документов типа 1 и типа 2. Сортировка типа asc или desc не учитывает наличие в строке поля сортировки типа 1 содержащихся чисел. Т.е. в случае с сортировкой desc выдает результат:

имя 9;

имя 8;

имя 3;

имя 19;

имя 18;

имя 13;

имя;

Я знаю, что это происходит из-за сортировки по полю типа keyword без его анализа, так как по полю типа text не сортируется в Elasticsearch.

Для поиска использую:

```
Spring Data Elasticsearch, 
ElasticsearchOperations 
Query filmQuery = NativeQuery.builder()...
```

Для сортировки указываю:

```
package org.springframework.data.domain;
public class Sort implements Streamable<Order>, Serializable {...}
sortParam.set(Sort.by("title.keyword").ascending());
```

Не могу понять, какие настройки в sortParam.set возможны/необходимы/существуют для получения сортировки с учетом чисел в поле keyword.

Есть мысль создать дополнительное поле, в котором будет отражено число, содержащееся в поле сортировки, для последующего его применения в качестве коэффициента для для повышения релевантности документов. Но как это сделать, не имею понятия.
Буду признателен за действенную помощь, еще больше за код возможного решения задачи.

Comment: Отформатируйте код в вопросе.